# Doctrine MappedSuperclass and unique constraints

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a scenario where I need to use the MappedSuperclass functionality of Doctrine (using Symfony2), and also create a unique constraint on some superclass columns. Let's say:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class Base
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $someColumn;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="column_idx", columns={"someColumn"})})
 */
class Concrete extends Base
{
}
```

The problem is at processing of @ORM\Table annotation during schema generation:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                          
There is no column with name 'someColumn' on table 'Concrete'.
```

Is there a way to define a unique constraint of a mapped superclass?

Comment: try `some_column`, because doctrine translates camelCase to underscore_case

Comment: @kmlnvm doesn't work - same error.

Comment: I've just tested it with camelCase and it works, I don't understand why you're getting error

Comment: generate entities, it could be caused by no getters/setters

Comment: I did some experimenting and var_dumped all the columns Doctrine sees while processing Table annotation (Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table class in Table.php). The exception is thrown by _createIndex() which cannot find the column in $this->_columns array, which is true since it's not there.

Comment: @kmlnvm getters and setters are created.

Comment: @krojew Try to use `protected` instead of `private` for entity field. You should always use `protected` or `public` for entity fields.

Comment: @user3749178 setting protected solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer author didn't post the answer himself, let me quote him:

> Try to use protected instead of private for entity field. You should always use protected or public for entity fields

Comment: In addition, i would like to say that it'll not work if the property is inside a Trait.